# Mysql LEFT JOIN multiple times

Tags: mysql, join

I run:

```
SELECT 
  t2.n, t3.n, t4.n,... tn.n 
FROM t1 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...) t2 ON t2.id = t1.c2 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...) t3 ON t3.id = t1.c3 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...) t4 ON t4.id = t1.c4
  ... 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...) tn ON t4.id = t1.cn
```

All contents in bracket are the same:

```
SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...
```

How can I call it 1 time instead of 'n' times as above?
t2.n, t3.n, t4.n,... tn.n have different values

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do

Comment: See normalisation (especially in regard to t1)

Comment: I need Select "t2.n, t3.n, t4.n,... tn.n" as different values

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try it you can try following code:

```
SELECT ... FROM t1 
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...) t2 
      ON 
        t2.id = t1.c2 OR 
        t2.id = t1.c3 OR 
        t2.id = t1.c4 OR
        t2.id = t1.cn
```

Comment: It didn't work. I need Select "t2.n, t3.n, t4.n,... tn.n" as different values

Comment: I thought you said 'All contents in bracket are same SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON...? Now you want different values? I am confused.

Comment: I said all strings: "SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON..." are same, but when they are joined with different conditions, output values (t2.n, t3.n...) are different.

Comment: can you post your table schema, its contents and expected output that you need?